# How to change the scope of a table search depending on a variable (VBA)

Tags: excel, vba, variables, range

I have A1 =1 which is the number of tables. If the value in the cell changes - a new table is added. I have a macro that searches it (code below). How can I make it search the range if I know that:

- distances between each table are constant (5 empty cells)
- table currently has fixed value (but will change in future)
- i know number of tables

I am looking for a way that, for each next table (A1), the range of searching it, will change to this added one.
I would especially ask for help with setting up .Range.

The mentioned code:

```
Sub pulling_row_number_if_it_finds_the_code_in_the_table()
                                                      
      Dim my_cell As Object
      Dim nr_row_code_found As Integer    
      Dim my_Range As Range

  With Worksheets("Sheet1")

Set my_Range = Range("A5:A50")

    For Each my_cell In my_Range
         If my_cell.Value = .Range("B1").Value Then 
         
             nr_row_code_found = my_cell.Row
            .Range("F1") = nr_ row_code_found
            
         End If
    Next my_cell
  End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Do the tables have a fixed number of rows?

Comment: Yes, it is currently fixed, but will be changed in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the tables are all the same size:

```vb
Sub pulling_row_number_if_it_finds_the_code_in_the_table()
                                                      
    Dim my_Range As Range, m, tblNum As Long
    Dim rngT1 As Range

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")

        Set rngT1 = .Range("A5:A50") 'first table
        tblNum = .Range("A1").Value
        Set my_Range = rngT1.Offset((tblNum - 1) * (rngT1.Rows.Count + 5))
        
        m = Application.Match(.Range("B1").Value, my_Range, 0)
        
        If Not IsError(m) Then 'if got a match
            .Range("F1") = my_Range.Cells(m).Row
        Else
            .Range("F1") = "no match"
        End If
        
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Cool!  That was it!